# Strange PHP form GET results

Tags: html, forms, get

I'm getting this GET url through to my php page:

```
suppliersdetails.php?project_no=107&submit=Submit+Query
```

Why would it grab the submit value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form has an `<input type="submit">` tag with a `name` attribute but no `value` attribute. In this situation, the default value submitted is `"Submit Query"`. You can prevent this by removing the `name` attribute from your `<input type="submit">` tag.

Answer (score 4):

Because your `<input type="submit" />` has a `name` (and, obviously, a `value`) and thus should be submitted, too. It is said to be "*successful*":

> A *successful control* is "valid" for submission. Every successful control has its control name paired with its current value as part of the submitted form data set. A successful control must be defined within a `FORM` element and must have a control name.

Source: [17.13.2 Successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls) ... you should take a look at this section.

Comment: ahh, is that right? I only thought it was strange as id never seen it come through like that before!

Comment: @benhowdle89 I believe it is :)

Comment: This answer mentions nothing about where the value "Submit Query"  comes from.

Comment: @Asaph No, it was implied in the "(and, obviously, a `value`)" part, i.e., "Submit Query" is the (default?) `value` of the button--and thus the text on the face of it. I see, however, that I never gave any hints as to default values :)

Comment: @jensgram: Yes. "Submit Query" is the default value when none is specified. It's an obscure feature supported by all major browsers. I doubt very much that the OP actually had `value="Submit Query"` in the in the html.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's the input value in the form,

And used to identify if there are more than one button on the page.

```
<input name="btn1" type="submit" value="Save and Return">
<input name="btn2" type="submit" value="Save and Insert More">

?btn1=Save and Return // you clicked "Save and Return"
```